# Извлечение всех значений из redis

Tags: php, redis

Доброго времени! В редис можно вывести значение по ключу так:

```
$value = $redis->get('message');
```

А можно ли как то получить в переменную ВСЕ значения из редис что бы к примеру вывести их в цикле foreach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую - нет, потому что они разных типов и их необходимо по-разному извлекать. Можно вытащить все ключи через `KEYS *` и затем получать значения по одному, но я не рекомендую это делать, потому что внутри может быть произвольный объем, и вы таким образом будете гонять мегабайты данных, забивая сеть.